# General Java Web App

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have a client server setup. I need my client to be able to call the server, and the server pass down either a file or the text contained in the file. I am new to web development. Which type of technologies should I investigate. I know that Java Web Services, Java Servlets, Java EE Applications all exist. But which one would be best for my uses? The server side application must be Java and run in Apache Tomcat.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: are you talking about a webclient or a Swing desktop client?

Comment: @hvgotcodes Its a swing desktop client

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/)

Answer (score 1):

Try Restlet in combination with Jetty container, but it works with any container (including Tomcat). [Here](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/21-restlet/318-restlet.html)  is where you can start.

[Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/) can be used for both desktop or in-browser web apps. Also it nicely integrates with Google Web Toolkit.